# Arch: broken lib-llvm dependency using postgresql on Manjaro

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, postgresql, llvm

I have a database server running Manjaro 20.0 and postgresql 12.1-2

A recent update has prevented complex queries from running - simple select queries execute ok, but larger select queries with joins generate the following error:

```
Error: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/llvmjit.so": libLLVM-9.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Checking pacman -Qi shows me that postgresql has as a dependency llvm-libs, and that this package updated from 9.0.1-2 to 10.0.0-1 when I updated a few days ago

I tried reverting llvm-libs to the 9.0.1-2 version in the pacman cache, but running the same query generates a similar error:

```
Error: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/llvmjit.so": libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems there is a dependency issue here that needs to be corrected - but I haven't found any relevant bug reports, and I'm not sure where I should direct this issue - to the Arch linux package repository, the llvm-libs maintainer, or postgresql maintainer?

And is there anything I can do to revert this issue in the meantime?

Comment: [I have the same problem with libffi.so.6](https://briandfoy.github.io/postgres-can-t-find-llvmjit-so/). I've turned of jit in postgres until all the packages catch up, I guess.

Comment: @briandfoy thanks, disabling jit has at least got me back up and running

Comment: I just got bit by the same symptom on Manjaro. I suppose I'll have to disable JIT as well.

Comment: I was the lucky recipient of a similar error when Manjaro upgraded postgres from 14 to 15 for me (I always forget to add it to ignore...), and I dutifully downgraded it back to 14 to avoid migrating my database using `pamac install downgrade && downgrade postgres`.
Trying to use a script gave the same error for llvmjit.so, saying libLLVM-14.so could not be found (because I had 15 now, too). Downgrading llvm to 14 solved the issue: `downgrade llvm`.